# MS access error 3075 keep showing after press search button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I m a newbie in programming, this is my first time to write a search form via access, actually i want to insert an ID in the text box and search its significant data, however it show me an error 3075 and highlighted the `Me.Recordsource = strsearch`, so any idea to correct it? thanks

here is the code that i write

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click() 
Dim strsearch As string
Dim strText As String
strText = Me.txtidsearchbox.Value
strsearch = "SELECT * from tblstudentinfo where ((ID like ""*" & strText &"*"")"
Me. RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub

Private Sub btnsearchall_Click()
Dim strsearch As String
strsearch = "SELECT * from tblstudentinfo"
Me.RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are unbalanced.

Change

```
strsearch = "SELECT * from tblstudentinfo where ((ID like ""*" & strText &"*"")"
```

To

```
strsearch = "SELECT * from tblstudentinfo where ID like ""*" & strText &"*"""
```

Note that you could use filters for this behavior, it's a more usual approach (e.g. `Me.Filter =  ID like ""*" & strText &"*"""`. `Me.FilterOn = True`)